# MySQL 8 install doesn't include mysql.exe (Windows). Where to get it from?

Tags: mysql, windows

I've installed MySQL 8.0 using mysql-installer-community-8.0.26.0.msi. Mainly these options:

[image]

But there's no binaries for connecting (mysql.exe) or dumping (mysqldump.exe):

[image]

What else do I need to install?

Comment: Are you looking for the mysql client executable? You've only installed the server as far as I can see

Comment: So what do I need to install? https://i.postimg.cc/FKYt31B9/install.png

Comment: Actually I think mysqlsh is the new, upgraded version of it? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-features.html

Comment: Either that, or maybe the file is in Program Files\MySql\bin?

Comment: Look at `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin`

Answer (score 0):

I would reconed also to install mysql workbench.

But you have an x64 operating system

so you are looking in the wrong place

> C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin

[image]

Comment: So do the mysql.exe and mysqldump.exe binaries come with the MySQL Workbench? because I put up a screenshot and that's all I have in that directory.

Comment: no the come woth the server version as does mysqld.exe, you are looking at the x86 program folder but mysql installs everything in the x64 foldr. Copy the folder from the quotation. workbench is pnly a gui to administer mysql server